# Multiple SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, select

Tengo 5 tablas con muchos registros. Cada tabla tiene columnas de "Fecha", en las que puede haber una sola fecha por usuario (se almacena la última fecha en que un usuario modificó su perfil, por ejemplo) o muchas fechas por usuario (las fechas en las que el usuario ha publicado uno o más anuncios). Cómo podría hacer una consulta para seleccionar todas las fechas de cada tabla teniendo en cuenta el usuario?

Por el momento tengo esto

```
SELECT DISTINCT Acept_Date, Marc_Fec, Cont_Mod, Emp_Mod, Dir_Mod
FROM anunciosaceptados, anunciosmarcados, contacto, datos_empresa, direcciones
WHERE Acept_usu = 'gmarsi' 
AND Marc_Usu = 'gmarsi'
AND Con_Usu = 'gmarsi'
AND Emp_Usu = 'gmarsi'
AND Dir_Usu = 'gmarsi'
```

y no me está funcionando, pues me muestra muchos registros repetidos como se ve en la imagen. La tablas que terminan en _Mod solamente guardan una fecha por usuario y me muestra muchas más
[image]

Comment: No estas utilizando relaciones y claves foraneas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás haciendo DISTINCT **NO** puede haber registros repetidos, el DISTINCT funciona de manera similar a un GROUP BY por cada campo, si los hubiera me atrevería a decir que es un problema de milisegundos y que las fechas siguen siendo distintas, solo que no se muestran estos milisegundos. Por otro lado, si cada tabla puede tener de 1 a N fechas distintas, es decir si en cada tabla las fechas no se repiten, y en definitiva quieres verlas todas, tampoco hace falta hacer un GROUP BY o un DISITNCT, lo que ocurre, es que hacer un producto cartesiano entre tablas, sin duda va a repetir fechas de una tabla por cada fecha distinta de otra de las tablas. Visualizarlas de esta forma no me parece la mejor idea, una vista más óptima tal vez sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT  'anunciosaceptados' AS 'Tabla',
    'Acept_Date'        AS 'Campo',
    Acept_Date      AS 'Valor'
    FROM anunciosaceptados
    WHERE Acept_usu = 'gmarsi' 

UNION

SELECT  'anunciosmarcados',
    'Marc_Fec',
    Marc_Fec
    FROM anunciosmarcados
    WHERE Acept_usu = 'gmarsi' 

UNION

SELECT  'contacto',
    'Cont_Mod',
    Cont_Mod
    FROM contacto
    WHERE Con_Usu  = 'gmarsi' 


UNION

SELECT  'datos_empresa',
    'Emp_Mod',
    Emp_Mod
    FROM datos_empresa
    WHERE Emp_Usu = 'gmarsi' 

UNION

SELECT  'direcciones',
    'Dir_Mod',
    Dir_Mod
    FROM direcciones
    WHERE Dir_Usu = 'gmarsi'
```

la idea de este query es retornar tal como fue tu pregunta, todas las fechas de cada tabla, en una única columna en este caso, indicando además la tabla y el campo al que hace referencia la fecha. Si tuvieras fechas repetidas en cada tabla, simplemente agregar un DISTINCT o GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que seguramente no tengas las tablas normalizadas y tengas mucha redundancia generando así muchos campos repetidos. **Es normal que salga muchas veces los campos _mod ya que saldrán tantas veces como fechas de los otros campos , aquellos que si pueden salir varias veces**. Si haces un GROUP BY seguramente  pierdas información.